# Understanding R syntax (using knots)

Tags: r, syntax

Being more MatLab than R, I ran into this bit of code:

```
z <- knots(y)
k <- ecdf(data)(z)
```

So knots is a interpolating step function so presumably the second line of code somehow "applies" this interpolation to empirical CDF of the data? How exactly do you read this syntax? What does it mean?

Comment: did you read `?knots` and `?ecdf`

Comment: No. `stepfun(x,y,...)` is the interpolating step function. `knots()` returns the x-points at which the values change.

Comment: ?knots just returns the documentation for the step function class (which is why I wrote it) to me. Hence I wrote that. Thanks for the clarification.